# why openssl rsa shows a different content of a certificate?

Tags: rsa, openssl

If I run `cat my.key`, I get:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAu+UkIRXNZrdcnuCLsBsz/HiBcYNoAAAhYi2hISKBxkqX165U...
```

but if I run `openssl rsa -in my.key`, I get a different content as:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJQwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCS0wggkpAgEAAoICAQC75SQhFc1mt1ye...
```

why the contents are different, shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: Compare (cross-stack) https://superuser.com/questions/606215/openssl-pkcs8-default-format-gives-rsa-private-key and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958304/pkcs1-and-pkcs8-format-for-rsa-private-key but beware those are from before 2021 when OpenSSL 3.0.0 changed the defaults as I note on fgrieu's answer. Also note this is a key (in two formats) NOT a certificate.

Answer (score 2):

The two base64 fragments in the question encode bytes which I show below in hex with spaces inserted to break things per [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1), and (for the first fragment corresponding to `my.key`) restore alignment with the second fragment.

```
                                                           30820929 020100 02820201 00BBE5242115CD66B75C9EE08BB01B33FC7881718368000021622DA1212281C64A97D7AE5454
30820943 020100 300D 0609 2A864886F70D010101 0500 0482092D 30820929 020100 02820201 00BBE5242115CD66B75C9E
```

We see that `openssl rsa -in my.key` has inserted a header of 26 bytes. As pointed by dave_thompson_085 in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/228736?noredirect=1), this header is for a `PrivateKeyInfo` as defined in [PKCS#8/RFC 5208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208.html#section-5). It's ASN.1 on the tune of:

```
SEQUENCE (0x0943=2371 bytes, 3 elements)
  INTEGER 0 // version
  SEQUENCE (0x0D=13 bytes, 2 elements) // privateKeyAlgorithm
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER (0x09=9 bytes) 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 // rsaEncryption (PKCS #1)
    NULL // parameters
  OCTET STRING (0x092D=2349 bytes) // privateKey (header)
```

The big picture is that this PKCS#8 header tells what follows, so that programs can consistently recognize that the private key is for RSA rather than another algorithm.

In this

- `version` is 0 (the first and AFAIK only PKCS#8 `PrivateKeyInfo` format)
- the `privateKeyAlgorithm` is a `PrivateKeyAlgorithmIdentifier`, which itself is an `AlgorithmIdentifier` per [PKCS#1v2.2 appendix C p.53](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=52), that is:

  - the [OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1](https://oid-rep.orange-labs.fr/get/1.2.840.113549.1.1.1) defined in [PKCS#1v2.2 appendix C p.52](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=52) for `rsaEncryption` (and also used for signature keys)
  - NULL, meaning there's no parameter.
- the `privateKey` in an OCTET STRING which bytes are the key itself, here an `RSAPrivateKey` SEQUENCE per [PKCS#1v2.2 appendix C p.56](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=56), with 9 elements. This wrapping allows PKCS#8 to wrap keys uniformly, regardless of if they are defined as a SEQUENCE, another ASN.1 type, or structured per some other convention.
- the optional `attributes` that could follow the key bytes is not present.

OpenSSL 3 by default uses PKCS#8 format to output keys, e.g.

```
openssl genrsa 4096
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:4096
```

Some OpenSSL tools have a flag to output the old format without PKCS#8 header, e.g.

```
openssl genrsa -traditional 4096
```

Note: the question disclosed the first bytes of the public modulus, but nothing confidential about the private key.

Comment: The difference is the RSA-specific structure defined by PKCS1 e.g. [rfc8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017.html#appendix-A.1.2) versus a PKCS8 structure defined in [rfc5208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208.html#section-5). To avoid confusion, note `openssl genrsa` and `openssl rsa` (both) output PKCS1 in older OpenSSL (through 1.1.1), and many existing Stack posts use and depend on this, but they default to PKCS8 and require `-traditional` for PKCS1 in OpenSSL 3.0.0 up. OTOH `req -newkey` or `genpkey` or `pkey` have output PKCS8 since 1.0.0.